# Rustlings move semantics.3 solution does not make sense to me

Tags: rust, rust-rustlings

Trying to learn Rust and got really confused with the solution from the `move_semantics3.rs` exercise.

Here is the exercise for reference:

```
// move_semantics3.rs
//
// Make me compile without adding new lines -- just changing existing lines! (no
// lines with multiple semicolons necessary!)

#[test]
fn main() {
    let vec0 = vec![22, 44, 66];

    let mut vec1 = fill_vec(vec0);

    assert_eq!(vec1, vec![22, 44, 66, 88]);
}

fn fill_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec.push(88);

    vec
}
```

And the solution, as the compiler itself will tell you is just to add the `mut` keyword into the `fill_ vec` function like so

```
fn fill_vec(mut vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>
```

However, I don’t get how you can get `vec0`, which is not defined as mutable and just pass it in as mutable in the function. Can you just magically transform an immutable vector into a mutable one by changing the function argument?

This is so confusing...

Comment: as `Vec<T>` does not implement the `Copy` trait, the `fill_vec` function takes ownership of the vector (meaning that you won't be able to use `vec0` after passing it to the function). As such, you can mutate it safely even though `vec0` is not mutable

Comment: @Liel Fridman This makes total sense to me, if you put it as an answer I will accept it as the valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the **value** that is mutable/not mutable, it's the **binding**.

Here, `vec0` is declared not-mutable, so no mutable access to the *value* is possible through *the binding* `vec0` (not accounting for interior mutability, which is beyond the scope of this question). When the *value* is passed to `fill_vec()` by means of *the binding* `vec0`, `fill_vec` receives either a copy of the value or the value itself (depending on `Copy`, again, beyond scope), and *binds the value* to a new variable `vec`. It is that *binding* `vec` which itself is declared `mut`, which allows for mutable access to *the value* behind `vec`.

Comment: Note that while `lex x` is not value immutable, `&x` is.